# Allow only one user at a time to land on page

Tags: django

I'm building an app where users can navigate through pages of `Treasure` objects.

Each treasure page has a `Next` button to reach the next available treasure, ordered by the ID on the database.

I want to **allow only one user to land on a specific treasure page**. Once the user reached the page, the `Treasure` instance is "owned" by that user (`treasure.captured_by = user`).

Therefore, the `Next` button should return the page of a treasure that has never been captured by other users. Unfortunately, when many users are connected, it happens sometimes that two users land on the same treasure page. How can I fix this?

### Example:

- User `A` is on the page `treasures/1`
- User `B` is on the page `treasures/2`
- Both users click on `Next` in the same exact moment.
- **What I want:** one of the two users goes to `treasures/3`, the other to `treasures/4`
- **What happens in reality:** both users are redirected to `treasures/3`, which is not correct.

---

The button calls a view which does something like:

```py
def get_next_available_treasure(request, current_treasure_id):
    """Retrieve the next unclaimed treasure."""

    treasure = Treasure.objects.filter(
        id__gt=current_treasure_id,  # Only consider Treasures that have been stored later on the db
        captured_by__isnull=True
    ).order_by('id').first()

    return redirect('treasure-page', treasure_id=treasure.id)
```

In `urls.py`:

```py
url(r'^go-to-next/(?P<current_treasure_id>\d+)/$',
    views.go_to_next_available_treasure,
    name='next-treasure'),
```

In the template:

```html
<a href="{% url 'textool:next-treasure' treasure.pk %}">Next</a>
```

**Question:** How can I fix the issue and have a sort of "lock" on the treasure page/instance?

---

#### Randomizing order

I thought about randomizing the order of the treasures when users click on `Next`. This would make it less likely to two users to land on the same page. However, I can't do this because I need to keep the order of treasures.

Comment: how are you passing the `current_treasure_id` to this view function? cam you show that?

Comment: Can you not just create a new treasure?

Comment: @Exprator I added the details you requested in the question above.

Comment: @Sayse Unfortunately, I can't. Treasures are created with a separate process and cannot be created on-the-fly.

Comment: is that random? or if users click on the next button the pk can be same?

Comment: @Exprator it is not random, it follows the order of insertion of the `Treasure` row on the database. So if two users click on `Next` at the same time, they can land on the same page. This is what I want to avoid by having some sort of lock.